# Como mudar o threshold de um modelo de classificação?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Além de prever classes diretamente, alguns modelos de *machine learning* geram vetores de probabilidade de pertencimento a cada uma das classes para cada observação na amostra. A classe predita de cada observação é a classe que supera um parâmetro estabelecido pelo pesquisador. Esse parâmetro é denominado *threshold* e tem como *default* 0.5.

Como minha amostra é muito desequilibrada, eu gostaria de mudar esse threshold para obter maior sensibilidade (taxa de verdadeiros positvos), mesmo que isso custe um pouco de especificidade (inverso da taxa de falsos negativos). É possível observar esse *trade-off* na ROC. Segue exemplo:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

data = pd.read_csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X=data.iloc[:,1:]
y=data['admit']

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

number_nb=1
logistic = LogisticRegression()
logistic.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = logistic.predict(X_test)

y_scores = logistic.predict_proba(X_test)
fpr, tpr, threshold = roc_curve(y_test, y_scores[:, 1])
roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,8))

ax.plot(fpr, tpr, 'k', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
ax.legend(loc = 'lower right')
ax.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'k--')
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_ylabel('Sensibilidade')
ax.set_xlabel('1-Especificidade')

plt.show()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria de saber é: como eu identifico a combinação de sensibilidade e especificidade associada ao threshold de 50%? Como faço para rodar um modelo com um valor de threshold apropriado para a combinação desejada de sensibilidade e especificidade?

Aqui um exemplo retirado do livro "Apllied predictive models":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução é simplesmente gerar um novo vetor de predições a partir do vetor de probabilidades de pertencimento da classe de referência.

Para obter os vetores de probabilidades, basta fazer:

```
y_scores=logistic.predict_proba(X_test)
```

No caso dos dados do exemplo que têm duas classes, `y_scores` tem duas colunas. A segunda coluna é que apresenta o vetor de probabilidades de pertencimento da classe de referência. Agora podemos gerar um novo vetor de predições:

```
pred2=pd.Series(y_scores[:,1]).map(lambda x: 1 if x > threshold else 0)
```

Onde `threshold` é o valor escolhido pelo pesquisador. Para ver a diferença, compare agora o `classification report` com os dois vetores de predição:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

print(classification_report(y_test, pred))
```

Retorna:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.72      0.97      0.82        90
           1       0.73      0.19      0.30        42

    accuracy                           0.72       132
   macro avg       0.72      0.58      0.56       132
weighted avg       0.72      0.72      0.66       132
```

E:

```py
threshold=0.3
pred2=pd.Series(y_scores[:,1]).map(lambda x: 1 if x > threshold else 0)

print(classification_report(y_test, pred2))
```

Retorna:

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.86      0.56      0.68        90
           1       0.46      0.81      0.59        42

    accuracy                           0.64       132
   macro avg       0.66      0.68      0.63       132
weighted avg       0.73      0.64      0.65       132
```

Note que a mudança aumentou a sensibilidade do modelo de 0.19 para 0.81