# Como fazer k-fold validation quanto altero o cut-off do modelo?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Quando reporto métricas de um modelo de machine-learning sempre utilizo o k-fold validation. Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedStratifiedKFold

data = pd.read_csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X=data.iloc[:,1:]
y=data['admit']

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

number_nb=1
mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2))
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = mlp.predict(X_test)
```

Com o modelo pronto, defino uma função para avaliar o modelo:

```py
def evaluate_model(X, y, model, metric):
    cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
    scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, scoring=metric, cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
    return np.mean(scores)
```

Avaliando a acurácia:

```py
evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, mlp,'accuracy')
```

Retorna:
0.6829 ...

Ocorre que gostaria de mudar o threshold de aceitação do modelo com o objetivo de escolher a combinação de sensibilidade e especificidade mais adequada ao meu caso concreto. Adotando o procedimento descrito nesta [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/485547/como-mudar-o-threshold-de-um-modelo-de-classifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o) consigo gerar o novo vetor de predições, mas com ele não é possível usar a função `cross_val_score`.

Existe uma forma de calcular métricas por k-fold validation quando se altera o cut-off do modelo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para associar um limiar diferente ao `MLPClassifier` mantendo a interface de otimização para o cross-validation, você pode encapsulá-lo em uma classe que herda de `BaseEstimator` e `ClassifierMixin`:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin

class CustomCutoffClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def __init__(self, model, cutoff):
        self.model = model
        self.cutoff = cutoff
    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
        return self
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1] > self.cutoff

mlp = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2))
model = CustomCutoffClassifier(mlp, 0.3)
evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, model, 'accuracy')
```

Alternativamente, você pode deixar o cutoff "hardcoded" em uma herança direta do MLPClassifier:

```
class MyMLPClassifier(MLPClassifier):
    def predict(self, X):
        return self.predict_proba(X)[:, 1] > 0.3

mlp = MyMLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5, hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2))
evaluate_model(X_train, y_train, mlp, 'accuracy')
```

Comment: Obrigado. Solução realmente criativa de criar um nova classe. Infelizmente, contudo, a função `cross_val_score` está retornando uma array de `nan` agora

Comment: Aparentemente o sklearn chia com a notação de atributo privado (`_attr`). Coloquei uma implementação alternativa caso a primeira não funcione.